# jqgrid editing form tabbed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm widely using jqgrid in a hotel web software management system I'm working on. 
Thanks to the advices the stackoverflow community gave me , everything works great!

I'm going to make a step over.
I'd like to improve user interface usability when users edit entity in jqgrid form editing. Actually, I'm using the standad look&feel where each rows are structured in a [long] list of fields. I know I could use rowpos e colpos ... Is It possible to create a tabbed interface in jqgrid form editing system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a complex form, your best bet may be to create your own custom edit form, instead of using the one built into jqGrid. For example, you can create a custom one based on jQuery UI dialog. I have done this in some of my applications, and have had the freedom to do anything on those forms, including adding tabs.

The obvious disadvantage is that you are building a UI custom to your application, and will need to handle getting data to/from the grid. In my case I could just pass an ID to the dialog and let that code retrieve the necessary information. I then setup and event to refresh the grid row after the dialog is closed.

Does that help?

Comment: thx Justin ... I've already done as You suggested ... I was trying to understand if jqgrid allows a standard way to create a custom edit form ... :( anyway, I'm going to mark this as the answer

Comment: No problem, I think this is the best way to go for any real-world application.